# What is the complete list of location where git objects are stored on disk?

Tags: git, git-plumbing

I have a git repo and I am trying to find where on disk a particular commit is stored.

1. `git show <HASH>` shows the commit.
2. `git cat-file -p <HASH>` shows the commit in raw form.
3. The commit is not under `.git/objects/`.
4. The commit is not under `.git/lfs/objects/`
5. It is not named inside `.git/packed-refs`
6. `grep -r <HASH>` and `find -name '*<PART_HASH>*'` does not have any results.

Questions:

- What location am I missing?
- Is there a command to find the location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git stores objects either as loose objects under a subdirectory of `.git/objects` or as a packed object in one of the packs in `.git/objects/pack`.  Packing objects stores them more efficiently because they can be stored as a delta (difference) against other objects.

If you want to find the pack in which an object is contained, you can list the corresponding index by piping one of the `.idx` files under `.git/objects/pack` to `git show-index`.  That will list the objects contained in the corresponding pack.

For example, in my local copy of `git/git`:

```
$ git show-index < .git/objects/pack/pack-0ebde31e89dd275864d40ae21ad3228a9dc7d0ea.idx | \
  head -n5
116264 0049c569260e2acbe490aabd267b233e9db28e8d (f0b1bf76)
182726 005e07db39e571eb3e73fbf7e4dbe5c67ad73e1e (29e2a47f)
99906 00c6aa0351c8d3abbcbee96d50cd7a359dd68a33 (e7952421)
477311 01724db3b51dc57d9e53e753148b5fbf548aa094 (0f597941)
186631 01b76e6be63bd19e446b3ede742bff887b7e81d5 (fd3f4a72)
```

The center portion is the object ID, which is probably what you're looking for.

Note that `packed-refs` contains only packed refs; if the object is not the head of any ref, then it won't appear there (or in any loose ref file).  Also note that core Git does not store anything under `.git/lfs/objects`, and the objects stored there by Git LFS are entirely separate and independent objects from Git objects, even if the repository is using SHA-256 for objects.